# How to enable autoplay on Instagram embedded video?

Tags: html, instagram, autoplay

I have a simple html page. **I dont want to use javascript or call Instagram API**. 
I would like to enable AutoPlay and Loop on Instagram video like we have with youtube:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[ID]?loop=1&controls=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Following the Instagram Help instructions:
https://help.instagram.com/513918941996087

And for Instagram:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/[ID]/embed/" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But I dont find a way to enable Autoplay and loop. Do you have an Idea?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I did not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ready call:

```
$('body > div > div.Content.EmbedFrame > div > div > div.fXIG0').click()
```